# Display entered text with echo after input PHP

Tags: php, html, text, textbox

I want to do something very simple. After a user enters text in an HTML text box then hits submit, the PHP echo's the entered text. I searched all over and I cant find out how to do it! There must be some way! I want something like this except `$foo` is what the entered text was.

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="something" value="$foo"/>
<html>
<?php
echo $foo = "ben";
echo "foo is $foo"; // foo is foobar


?>
```

Comment: You want to do it at the same time without a page reload or when the page is submitted?

Comment: Got your answer below i guess. The trick here is that you need to wrap your `input` inside a `form`. If you wanted to achieve this at the same time then you would need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FTFY

```
<html>
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="something" value="<?= isset($_POST['something']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['something']) : '' ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo 'You entered: ', htmlspecialchars($_POST['something']);
}
?>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: +100 for `htmlspecialchars` - I use it but in this context I would certainly forget about that! :-)

Comment: I want the PHP in a separate file. How do I change that so it will work??

Comment: Change the `action` attribute of the form to point to the script

Comment: Simple and Great !