# I want to send the values entered by the user in a text input on PHP, through a form in HTML

Tags: php, html, textbox

I have a table in HTML coded inside PHP, which has 3 editable text boxes for the user to edit and a submit button. My code looks as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0 border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th><b>First Name</b></th><th><b>Surname</b></th><th><b>Favourite Colour</b></th></tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"t1\" size=\"25\" value=\"text 1\" /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"t2\" size=\"25\" value=\"text 2\" /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"t3\" size=\"25\" value=\"text 3\" /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br /><br />";
    ?>  

    <form method=post action=display.php>
        <input type="hidden" name="text1" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="text2" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="text3" value="]">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside my form, I want to set the value="", to the value the user has entered above for each respective box. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display entered text with echo after input PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046353/display-entered-text-with-echo-after-input-php)

Comment: hum... Did you just try to put your table inside your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript for that.

```
<script> 
document.getElementsByName("text1").value = document.getElementsByName("t1").value;
document.getElementsByName("text2").value = document.getElementsByName("t2").value;
document.getElementsByName("text3").value = document.getElementsByName("t3").value;
</script>
```

Comment: The core login is here, but you don't explain how and when you trigger this code